# Contradiction with accepted answer descriptions

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, tour

I've noticed a contradiction in the wording. The [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) says this:

> *Accepting **doesn't mean it's the best answer**, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.*

But the hover text for accepted answers (i.e. hover on the green tick graphic) says this:

> The question owner accepted this as the **best answer** < time >.

So is the accepted answer the "best answer" or isn't it? These two descriptions really ought to be consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## We can't do anything about it

From [mxyzplk's comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8578/contradiction-with-accepted-answer-descriptions#comment27521_8580) from [GreySage's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8580/35259):

> We can’t [modify the hover text], as we can’t edit any other automated text on the site except one small part of the help center.

And from [doppelgreener's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8576/35259) to a different question about the tour:

> We can't actually edit that part of the tour just for this site, so this is a Stack Exchange dev thing.

Answer (score 10):

It is the answer the OP considers the best, that helps them the most with their problem.

That does not mean it is the objectively best one.  Feel free and vote for the answer(s) you like.

However, the accepted answer is at the OP’s sole discretion and it can’t be “appealed.”  We get flags with people saying “they accepted answer X but I think it’s wrong!”  Irrelevant/don’t care.

Comment: To clarify, this isn't about disputing which answer is accepted; I agree that it's irrelevant, the OP chose what they chose and that's that. My issue was simply with the semantics; one says "best answer" and the other explicitly contradicts that by saying "doesn't mean it's the best answer".

Comment: It’s worth mentioning because that’s the #1 misconception we get around accepting answers.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps we should modify the hover text to read:

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer for them < time >.

or

> The question owner accepted this as the answer that worked for them < time >.

*This assumes we can modify such things, and I don't actually know if we can or not*

Comment: We can’t, as we can’t edit any other automated text on the site except one small part of the help center.